# Cakephp display other model associated with foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, cakephp-2.0

I have the models Item and Actor with a HABTM relation ***(working fine)***.

Now, I added the **Role model**, wich holds the actorid, itemid (as foreign key) and the actors' role.

In my Item view, I'd like to display the actor and its' role.
I have set recursive =2.

When I debug $items, I receive all the roles belonging to that actor.
**Instead I'd like only the role displayed, that contains the viewed itemid AND actorid.**

I believe I might need to tweak my models but don't know how.. Any suggestions?

**Item Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany  = array( 
            'Actor' => array(
            'className' => 'Actor',
            'joinTable' => 'item2actor',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'actor_id',
            'unique' => 'true'
));
public $hasMany = array(
            'Role' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
            'foreignKey' => 'actorid',  
));
```

**Actor Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany  = array(
        'Item' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'joinTable' => 'item2actor',
            'foreignKey' => 'actor_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'item_id',
            'unique' => 'true'));
public $hasMany = array(
         'Role' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
            'foreignKey' => 'actorid',  
));
```

Comment: this is done, I found a way using a -very large- find query and set recursive to -1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a -very large- query and recursive I suggest using Containable behavior with which it's much easier to maintain the data you want to receive from DB.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html @ Cake Book.